# Removing <p> elements with no text with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Given an HTML document in Nokogiri, I want to remove all `<p>` nodes with no actual text. This includes `<p>` elements with whitespace and/or `<br/>` tags. What's the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with a method like this one (feel free to monkeypatch `Nokogiri::XML::Node` if you want to)

```
def is_blank?(node)
  (node.text? && node.content.strip == '') || (node.element? && node.name == 'br')
end
```

Then continue with another method that checks that all children are blank:

```
def all_children_are_blank?(node)
  node.children.all?{|child| is_blank?(child) } 
  # Here you see the convenience of monkeypatching... sometimes.
end
```

And finally, get the `document` and

```
document.css('p').find_all{|p| all_children_are_blank?(p) }.each do |p|
  p.remove
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `node.content.strip` instead?

Answer (score 9):

This is a simpler fix: it removes both the whitespace and the `br` tags.

given the HTML

```
"<p>  </p><p>Foo<p/><p><br/> <br>   </p>"
```

**Solution:**

```
document.css('p').find_all.each do |p|
    # Ruby on Rails Solution:
    p.remove if p.content.blank?

    # Ruby solution, as pointed out by Michael Hartl:
    p.remove if p.content.strip.empty?
end
# document => <p>Foo</p>
```

Comment: The `blank?` method isn't part of vanilla Ruby. (It's available in Rails apps due to Active Support.) I believe a working replacement for `p.content.blank?` is `p.content.strip.empty?`.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I blindly assumed he was using RoR... Updated my answer :)

Comment: Be careful - if you have a <p> with only non-textual nodes inside (img, video, audio, etc.), then `p.content` will return an empty string.

Comment: yep <p><br /><p> wouldn't be removed then ?

Comment: <p><br/></p> would be removed as it's empty. @bricker's warning is about img and audio tags being removed, though you might want to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

There's a more elegant way:

```
require "nokogiri"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-EOHTML
<div>
  <p class="empty_p"></p>
  <p class="full_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
EOHTML

# Magic happens here...
doc.at_css("p:first-child:empty").remove

puts doc.to_html
```